# HTML/CSS/jQuery Wrap Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is the best way to align this to show properly, like in this picture: [image: closed layout]

HTML markup:

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="article-thumbnail-1" class="article-thumbnail">
    <div class="article-open"><img src=".../article-open.png" /></div>
    <div class="article-close"><img src=".../artcle-close.png" /></div>
  </div>
  <article id="article-1" class="article-entry">
    <header class="article-header">
      <h2>This is the article 1 text</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="article-body">
      <p>This is the article 1 body</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <div id="article-thumbnail-2" class="article-thumbnail">
    <div class="article-open"><img src=".../article-open.png" /></div>
    <div class="article-close"><img src=".../artcle-close.png" /></div>
  </div>
  <article id="article-2" class="article-entry">
    <header class="article-header">
      <h2>This is the article 2 text</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="article-body">
      <p>This is the article 2 body</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <div id="article-thumbnail-3" class="article-thumbnail">
    <div class="article-open"><img src=".../article-open.png" /></div>
    <div class="article-close"><img src=".../artcle-close.png" /></div>
  </div>
  <article id="article-3" class="article-entry">
    <header class="article-header">
      <h2>This is the article 3 text</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="article-body">
      <p>This is the article 3 body</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <div id="article-thumbnail-4" class="article-thumbnail">
    <div class="article-open"><img src=".../article-open.png" /></div>
    <div class="article-close"><img src=".../artcle-close.png" /></div>
  </div>
  <article id="article-4" class="article-entry">
    <header class="article-header">
      <h2>This is the article 4 text</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="article-body">
      <p>This is the article 4 body</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <div id="article-thumbnail-5" class="article-thumbnail">
    <div class="article-open"><img src=".../article-open.png" /></div>
    <div class="article-close"><img src=".../artcle-close.png" /></div>
  </div>
  <article id="article-5" class="article-entry">
    <header class="article-header">
      <h2>This is the article 5 text</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="article-body">
      <p>This is the article 5 body</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <div id="article-thumbnail-6" class="article-thumbnail">
    <div class="article-open"><img src=".../article-open.png" /></div>
    <div class="article-close"><img src=".../artcle-close.png" /></div>
  </div>
  <article id="article-6" class="article-entry">
    <header class="article-header">
      <h2>This is the article 6 text</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="article-body">
      <p>This is the article 6 body</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

So basically if you click on an img thumbnail article should appear below it like in this picture: [image: this picture]

I am having issues with, when an article is opened and displayed below it, to keep the thumbnails layout.

Basically, when you click on a thumbnail, the article should appear below the the line of thumbnails from which the clicked thumbnail is.

Note, I am doing this for a WordPress theme.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PkZrZ/

Comment: Could you setup a fiddle to play with?

Comment: It's added, the fiddle example

Comment: Will it always have 3 boxes in width?

Comment: Yes, it will have. And you may consider the boxes dimensions fixed aswell.

Comment: just flying by, but thumbs up for a very well formatted question. not seeing this very often!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simpliest solution. It depends on data attribute of tumbnail. So if it is unacceptably to add data attribute to tumbnail tag let me know and I'll try to do something else.
http://jsfiddle.net/d3D9p/

I've changed the order of elements. There are three tumbnails folowed by three articles.
(Same for the forth to sixth)

```
<div id="main">
<div class="article-thumbnail" data-num="1">
    <div class="article-open"><img src="" /></div>
    <div class="article-close"><img src="" /></div>
</div>


<div class="article-thumbnail" data-num="2">
    <div class="article-open"><img src="" /></div>
    <div class="article-close"><img src="" /></div>
</div>
<div class="article-thumbnail" data-num="3">
    <div class="article-open"><img src="" /></div>
    <div class="article-close"><img src="" /></div>
</div>
<article id="article-1" class="article-entry">
    <header class="article-header">
        <h2>This is the article 1 text</h2>     
    </header>
    <div class="article-body">
        <p>This is the article 1 body</p>       
    </div>
</article>
<article id="article-2" class="article-entry" >
    <header class="article-header">
        <h2>This is the article 2 text</h2>     
    </header>
    <div class="article-body">
        <p>This is the article 2 body</p>       
    </div>
</article>
<article id="article-3" class="article-entry">
    <header class="article-header">
        <h2>This is the article 3 text</h2>     
    </header>
    <div class="article-body">
        <p>This is the article 3 body</p>       
    </div>
</article>
```

Also new jquery:

Hide every article and then show only that is coresponds to selected tumbnail.

```
$('.article-thumbnail').click(function() {
    $('.article-entry').css({"display": "none"});
    $('#article-'+$(this).data("num")).css({"display": "block"});
});
```

**UPD:** Can't test it myself now. But you can try something like folow:
First of all read about [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) if not yet.
You can grab all posts:

```
&get_posts()
```

Then combining simple php loop and

```
next_post()
```

you can display exact number of posts that you want to, before adding a tumbnail. 
Hope it helps you somehow.

If this doesn't help you can nest loop that will show articles within loop that will show thumbnails and after every third run of tumbnail_loop run articles_loop that will display three of it and returns to tumbnail_loop.

Comment: It seems to work correctly, going to test it in wordpress. (I cleared the fiddle).

Comment: Now after I tested a little in wordpress, I realized it won't work because the wordpress loop uses a while(), and I can only get all the artiles or all the thumbnails togheter.
http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Answer (score 1):

You have your markup like this:

```
<div id="article-thumbnail-1" class="article-thumbnail">
        <div class="article-open"><img src=".../article-open.png" /></div>
        <div class="article-close"><img src=".../artcle-close.png" /></div>
    </div>
    <article id="article-1" class="article-entry">
        <header class="article-header">
            <h2>This is the article 1 text</h2>     
        </header>
        <div class="article-body">
            <p>This is the article 1 body</p>       
        </div>
    </article>
```

so, you have placed the content of any thumbnail i.e. `article` directly adjacent to the block. that's why when you click on a given block i.e div.`article-thumbnail`, the related `article` element  get rendered there it self i.e adjacent to it. hence the flow i.e your layout changes.

you need to change your markup.

do this.

place all your thumbnails separate and their article counterpart separate.

something like

```
|<Upper Thumbnails Section>|
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|<upper article container>| //invisible by default

|<Lower Thumbnails Section>|
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|<lower article container>| //invisible by default
```

see this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PkZrZ/4/).

i.e.

```
<div class="article-thumbnail" data-target="article-1" >
     ..
     ..
</div>
<div class="article-thumbnail" data-target="article-2" >
     ..
     ..
</div>
<div class="article-thumbnail" data-target="article-3" >
     ..
     ..
</div>

<div class="container">
   <article id="article-1" class="article-entry">
   </article>
   <article id="article-2" class="article-entry">
   </article>
   <article id="article-3" class="article-entry">
   </article>
 </div>
```

and toggle your content with a script like this:

```
var prev;
$('.article-thumbnail').click(function() {
    var _target= $(this).data("target");
    var _current=$('#'+_target);
    var hideCss={'height':'0px'};
    var showCss={'height':'200px'};

    if(prev){
        prev.hide();
        prev.parent().stop().animate(hideCss,1000);
    }
    _current.show();
    _current.parent().stop().animate(showCss,1000);

    prev= _current
});
```

Comment: It's very good, but won't work with the Wordpress Loop http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop. This page is basically a category arhive listing.